# Overwriting single files securely in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, delete-file, erase

I am making a disk nuker and secure file deleter in vb.net, the nuking part is fine, but I am wondering, will opening a file using the System.IO class, and then write data until the end is reached make the file unrecoverable as if it was overwritten after deletion?

Comment: In short, no.  All you do in the second case is change the contents of the file. The file may be unusable, but it is still there, it can still be opened and it can still be read.

Comment: @Tim, but will the data that was origionaly there be recoverable? Suppose i overwrote the content by seeking byte position 0 and then write random or useless data until end of file and then deleted it using the system.io class... will the origional content be recoverable?

Comment: There's residual magnetism because the disk drive head isn't perfectly aligned on the track.  Forensic labs use hyper-sensitive hall effect sensors to recover that.  Doing this securely requires being able to control the drive head directly, making it seek to the track from multiple directions and scrub the track to increase the odds that misalignment is distributed evenly.  The ability of the drive to remap bad sectors doesn't help either, it leaves traces.  The kind of low-level access to the drive you need makes this all rather impractical.  A secure disk nuker is simple, use a shredder.

Comment: You might want to consider the information on the [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443) page. However, it does not mention SSDs, which you can research further (the TRIM command may suffice).

Comment: @HansPassant (and anyone else, of course) - rather than an industrial-strength shredder, if you disassemble a HDD you typically get two very strong magnets into the bargain. Safety note: the platter(s) may be made of glass. A domestic oven may not get hot enough to exceed the Curie point of the magnetic material; sandpaper will destroy the integrity of the data, but then you won't have a round mirror any more.

Comment: @Hans Passant all disk nukers have problems with magnetic traces, following the logic that magnetical traces can be found on the surrounding bits of any given bit, then will nuking the entire harddrive be safer than overwriting single parts like a file? However, the likelyhood of shadow data decreases as the bit density increases, which is why many scientists argue that the bit density of mordern drives is so high that recovery based on extracting shadow data trough microscopy is no longer plausible...